# Using `map` to find rowMeans by column names

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a dataset with consistently named columns and I would like to take the average of the columns by their group e.g.,

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(glue)

df <- tibble(`1_x_blind` = 1:3, 
       `1_y_blind` = 7:9,
       `2_x_blind` = 4:6, 
       `2_y_blind` = 5:7)
  
df %>% 
  mutate(`1_overall_test` = rowMeans(select(., matches(glue("^1_.*_blind$")))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   `1_x_blind` `1_y_blind` `2_x_blind` `2_y_blind` `1_overall_test`
#>         <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>            <dbl>
#> 1           1           7           4           5                4
#> 2           2           8           5           6                5
#> 3           3           9           6           7                6
```

This method works fine. The next step for me would be to scale it so that I can do the entire series of columns e.g., something like

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(overall_blind = map(1:2, ~rowMeans(select(., matches(glue("^{.x}_.*_blind$"))))))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `overall_blind`.
#> x no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
#> ℹ Input `overall_blind` is `map(1:2, ~rowMeans(select(., matches(glue("^{.x}_.*_blind$")))))`.
```

I think the problem here is that `select` is confusing the `.` operator. Is it possible to `map` over a series of column names in this way? Ideally I'd like the column names to follow the `{.x}_overall` pattern as in the example above.

Comment: Do you want your output to have only 1 extra `overall_blind` column of lists to store the row means of all subgroups, or would you like many columns like `1_overall_test`, `2_overall_test`, etc.?

Comment: It would be better to have many columns

Comment: The number of columns per group is fixed (always 2, i.e., 1_x, 1_y), or they vary per group?

Comment: The number will always be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** Here's a cleaner way that doesn't require `rename` or `bind_cols`:

```r
map_dfc(1:2, 
        function(x) df %>% 
          select(matches(glue("^{x}_.*_blind$"))) %>%
          mutate("{x}_overall_blind" := rowMeans(.))
        )

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  `1_x_blind` `1_y_blind` `1_overall_blind` `2_x_blind` `2_y_blind` `2_overall_blind`
        <int>       <int>             <dbl>       <int>       <int>             <dbl>
1           1           7                 4           4           5               4.5
2           2           8                 5           5           6               5.5
3           3           9                 6           6           7               6.5
```

**Previous**
Here's a `map` approach.
The challenge is mutating two new columns based on separate groups of existing columns.  Easiest just to do that in its own `map_dfc()` and then bind that to the existing `df`.

```r
df %>%
  bind_cols(
    map_dfc(1:2, ~rowMeans(df %>% select(matches(glue("^{.x}_.*_blind$"))))) %>%
      rename_with(~paste0(str_replace(., "\\...", ""), "_overall_blind"))
  )

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  `1_x_blind` `1_y_blind` `2_x_blind` `2_y_blind` `1_overall_blind` `2_overall_blind`
        <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>             <dbl>             <dbl>
1           1           7           4           5                 4               4.5
2           2           8           5           6                 5               5.5
3           3           9           6           7                 6               6.5
```

And here's a way to get your rowwise column-group averages using pivots, which avoids regex and `mutate`/`map` operations:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  separate(name, c("grp"), sep = "_", extra = "drop") %>%
  group_by(row, grp) %>%
  summarise(overall_blind = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = row, names_from = grp, values_from = overall_blind, 
              names_glue = "{grp}_{.value}") %>%
  bind_cols(df)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  `1_overall_blind` `2_overall_blind` `1_x_blind` `1_y_blind` `2_x_blind` `2_y_blind`
              <dbl>             <dbl>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>
1                 4               4.5           1           7           4           5
2                 5               5.5           2           8           5           6
3                 6               6.5           3           9           6           7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
map_dfc(1:2, function(x) {
  select(df, matches(glue("^{x}_.*_blind$"))) %>%
    mutate(overall_blind = rowMeans(select(., matches(glue("^{x}_.*_blind$"))))) %>%
    
    # General but not perfect names
    # set_names(paste0(x, "_", names(.)))
    
    # Hand-tailored names
    set_names(c(names(.)[1], names(.)[2], paste0(x, "_", names(.)[3])))
  })

#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   `1_x_blind` `1_y_blind` `1_overall_blind` `2_x_blind` `2_y_blind` `2_overall_blind`
#>         <int>       <int>             <dbl>       <int>       <int>             <dbl>
#> 1           1           7                 4           4           5               4.5
#> 2           2           8                 5           5           6               5.5
#> 3           3           9                 6           6           7               6.5
```

I added two possibilities of naming the `overall_blind` column for each group, one more general but not perfect names (it duplicates the `1_` or `2_` for the data columns), and another that gives the names that you want but require knowing in advance the number of columns per group.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split.default` to split the data into `list` of datasets based on the column name pattern, then get the `rowMeans` and bind with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
      split.default(readr::parse_number(names(.))) %>%
      map_dfc(rowMeans) %>% 
      set_names(str_c(names(.), "_overall_blind")) %>%
      bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  `1_x_blind` `1_y_blind` `2_x_blind` `2_y_blind` `1_overall_blind` `2_overall_blind`
#        <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>             <dbl>             <dbl>
#1           1           7           4           5                 4               4.5
#2           2           8           5           6                 5               5.5
#3           3           9           6           7                 6               6.5
```